# Get addresses from TIGER geocoder in polygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I have the TIGER geocoder installed, setup and working in POSTGIS.  I also see the reverse geocoder lets me get an address from a point on the map.

But now I want to provide a polygon and get all the addresses within the polygon.  Is this possible without trying to iterate over all possible points in the polygon?  (How would that even be accomplished?)

Best,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not an optimal solution, but it should be workable.

It should be possible to get a list of all streets from the tiger data tables. If you can limit the polygon to state or zipcode, you can filter the streets by state or zipcode first.

Use `ST_Crosses` to test which street crossed your polygon. Then check the address range for each street to further narrow down to street addresses.

Note the street numbers are interpolated and there could be lots of variation. See [reason here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/115666).